# Modify application context in TestExecutionListener before Spring Boot autoconfiguration phase

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-boot-test

Is there a way to modify the application context in a TestExecutionListener (or anywhere else) **before** Spring Boot's autoconfiguration is ran?

I would like to register a specific bean in my test context so that Spring Boot doesn't autoconfigure its own (because of `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`), but in some cases would like to *remove* the registered bean so that the autoconfig kicks in (because of the missing bean condition).

Or maybe there is another way to force a specific autoconfig to load? Although this is somewhat less desirable because it wouldn't exactly match how it works in production.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. If I were you, I would use a profile driven setup instead of playing around with auto configuration options. Have a look at this tutorial as well https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-auto-configuration

Comment: @aksappy "There are many ways to do this". Would you mind listing some that come to your mind, even without long explanation? I could then go find the details myself.

Comment: 1. Beans with primary scopes within tests 2. Use of ConditionalOnProperty and overriding property in tests 3. Mocked bean alongside actual bean 4. Separate tests based on the bean scope 5. Tests that has different profiles or contexts set up